# Some images appear discoloured in Firefox

Tags: firefox, display, color-management

Some images appear green-ish and purple-ish when I view them using Firefox, but when I open the same page using Chromium the image colour is normal.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Screenshot? Press Alt+PrntScreen, it will save to your Pictures folder. Upload to http://imgur.com

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/901959

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved - the issue was the same as [this one on the Firefox Forums](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/901959).

> That can be caused by a problem with the color profile for your display monitor or color profiles embedded in images.
>
> You can disable color management to test that.
>
> You can set the pref `gfx.color_management.mode` to `0` on the `about:config` page to disable Color Management.
>
> You need to close and restart Firefox to make the change effective.
>
> See:
>
> - http://kb.mozillazine.org/gfx.color_management.mode